# jQuery - AJAX error: does not re-enable submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have been working to get code which stops the user from sending multiple AJAX requests. `.one()` does not work for me. I have decided to use  `.prop('disabled');` on my "submit" button to stop it from being able to send any more AJAX requests.

The theory for the flow-line was: user clicks submit button. send AJAX. disable submit. AJAX finishes. re-enable submit button.

I [tried](https://jsfiddle.net/4lackof/hoe08dpq/1/) to put that to the test, but seems to not be working. Here's a snippet of my code (same as the jsfiddle I just linked):

```js
//runs on $(document).ready();
console.log($('#submit').prop('disabled'));

$(document).on('click', '#submit', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/FakeURL',
    })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      $('#gimme-data').append(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $('#gimme-data').append(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    })
    .always(function(data_jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR_errorThrown) {
      $('#gimme-data').append(data_jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR_errorThrown);
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', 'false');
      console.log($('#submit').prop('disabled'));
    });
});
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $('#submit').prop('disabled', 'true');
  console.log($('#submit').prop('disabled'));
}).ajaxStop(function() {
  $('#submit').prop('disabled', 'false');
  console.log($('#submit').prop('disabled'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="submit" class="first" value="GO!" title="Log In">
<div id="gimme-data">

</div>
```

As you can see when you run it, `$('#submit').prop('disabled')` always stays true (except, at the beginning, before anything happens).

This is after `$('#submit').prop('disabled', 'false');` gets set on both `.ajaxStop();` AND `.always()`;

> Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a *boolean* value to the `prop` method as `disabled` is a boolean property. The `'false'` is non-empty string which is coerced into the `true` boolean value. Use `false` instead.